# Fade in/out label with strings from array

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6, uilabel

```
func setOverlayTitle() {
    self.overlayLogo!.text = "Welcome"
    var hello: [String] = ["Bon Jour", "GUTEN\nMORGEN", "BONJOUR", "HOLA", "안녕하세요", "BUENOS DÍAS", "BUONGIORNO", "早安", "おはよう", "गुड मॉर्निंग"]

    for (var i = 1; i < hello.count-1; i++) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 2.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.overlayLogo!.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: {
            (finished: Bool) -> Void in
            println(i)
            self.overlayLogo!.text = hello[i]

            // Fade in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
                self.overlayLogo!.alpha = 1.0
                }, completion: nil)
    })
  }

}
```

I have the following code and I'm trying to iterate through the array "hello" while fade in/out the label with a 2 second delay. But this code won't work!
Currently it just prints the number 9, 9 times and fades in/out only once

Comment: Have traced through the code with breakpoints? What parts don't work? What errors show up?

Comment: Why do you start i at 1? It should be: `for (var i = 0; i < hello.count-1; i++)`

Comment: @ShaanSingh doesn't make any difference though

Comment: Yeah, I'm still looking at your code. Just pointing out that quick fix though.

Comment: Try changing the text by hardcoding it in: `self.overlayLogo!.text = "test"`. Does that work? If it does, then that narrows down the problem.

Comment: @ShaanSingh it fades into test and does nothing else!

Comment: Can you println the overlayLogo text right after where you set it to the array element and tell me the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is caused by the `for` loop you are using there. You can't get the desired behavior in that way. `for` loop won't wait for your label animation to complete before starting the next iteration. Instead of that, you can make a recursive call from the method itself after each animation cycle completes.

You need to declare a variable in your class and implement the method like below:

**Update for Swift 5 and Above:**

```
var iterator = 1;
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
        
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.lblAnime!.text = "Welcome"
   setOverlayTitle()
}
    
func setOverlayTitle() {
   let hello: [String] = ["Bon Jour", "GUTEN\nMORGEN", "BONJOUR", "HOLA", "안녕하세요", "BUENOS DÍAS", "BUONGIORNO", "早安", "おはよう", "गुड मॉर्निंग"]
        
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 2.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            
      self.lblAnime!.alpha = 0.0
   }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
            
      self.lblAnime!.text = hello[self.iterator]
            
      // Fade in
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
                
         self.lblAnime!.alpha = 1.0
      }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
                
         self.iterator += 1
         if self.iterator < hello.count {
            self.setOverlayTitle();
         }
      })
   })
}
```

**Original Answer (Older versions of Swift):**

```
var iterator = 1;

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.lblAnime!.text = "Welcome"
    setOverlayTitle()
}

func setOverlayTitle()
{
    
    var hello: [String] = ["Bon Jour", "GUTEN\nMORGEN", "BONJOUR", "HOLA", "안녕하세요", "BUENOS DÍAS", "BUONGIORNO", "早安", "おはよう", "गुड मॉर्निंग"]
    
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 2.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations:
       {
            self.lblAnime!.alpha = 0.0
       },
       completion:
       {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
            println(self.iterator)
            self.lblAnime!.text = hello[self.iterator]
                
            // Fade in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations:
                {
                     self.lblAnime!.alpha = 1.0
                },
                completion:
                {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
                     self.iterator++
                        
                     if self.iterator < hello.count
                     {
                         self.setOverlayTitle();
                     }
                })
       })
}
```