# how to show array of multiple text in one label by fade in and fade out

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show multiple quotation in one label and at a time only one quotation appear and quotation is coming from server side in array.
I am doing this -:

```
for i in self.splashModel?.quotations ?? [] {
        self.quoteLabel.alpha = 0
            self.quoteLabel.text = i
            self.quoteLabel.fadeIn(completion: {
                    (finished: Bool) -> Void in
                    self.quoteLabel.fadeOut()
                    })
       
    }
```

this code show only last quotation of array.

Comment: Your for loop is "faster than then animation". What you want is to change the text, animated, and when it ends, do it again...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fade in/out label with strings from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443739/fade-in-out-label-with-strings-from-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
self.splashModel?.quotations.enumerated().forEach { (index,item) in
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double( index * 2) ) {
        self.quoteLabel.alpha = 0
        self.quoteLabel.text = item
        self.quoteLabel.fadeIn(completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
           self.quoteLabel.fadeOut()
       })
    } 
}
```